# How do I put 2 floating <div> elements center of the container <div> next to each other?

Tags: css, html

I have 2 div elements "date1' and "date2" in parent `div` dates. I can put them next to each other but both align either left or right. But i want them at *center* next to each other like, [ o o ] not [oo  ]

```
#date1 {
float: left;
width: 32%;

text-align: center;

padding: 2px;


}

#date2 {
float: left;
    width: 32%;

text-align: center;
padding: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using flex:

```css
#date1 {
background-color:green;
float: left;
width: 32%;
  height:200px;
text-align: center;
padding: 2px;
}
#date2 {
float: left;
width: 32%;
  height:200px;
text-align: center;
padding: 2px;
  background-color:blue;
}
.row{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="date1">
    </div>
    <div id="date2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try it using `display:inline-block;`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="date1">
    </div>
    <div id="date2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css would be

```
.row{
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
//your other css
}
.date1 .date2{
vertical-align:top;
//your other css
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
display:inline-block
```

instead of

```
'float:left'.
```

try this fiddle

```
https://jsfiddle.net/92q5xr3p/
```